# Write value of range to thumb slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to write the value of range input to the thumb. I looked to every single question about this I could find on Google and I didn't find a solution.
I also want to when the value is `10001` I want it to show `∞` instead.

I have tried:

```js
$('#km').on('input', function() {
  if ($(this).val() === "10001") {
    console.log("infinity");
    $(this).addClass("range-infinite")
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("range-infinite");
  }
});
```

```css
.range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-apperance: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #1299E6, #A0D9F9);
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 70px;
  height: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  border-top: none;
}

.range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-apperance: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 80px;
  background: #1299E6;
  border: 1px solid #A0D9F9;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.range::-webkit-slider-thumb::before {
  content: attr(data-val)
}

.range-infinite::before {
  content: "∞";
}

.range input[type=range] {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="range-div">
  <input type="range" name="" id="" class="range">
</div>
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `-moz-apperance: none;` you have a typo here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:before` and `:after` pseudo will not work on *Form Action* elements like `input`.
Instead use a `span` for example.

```js
$('.range').on('input', function() {

  var val = parseInt( this.value, 10 );
  var v = val >= parseInt(this.max, 10) ? '∞' : val;
  $(this).next('span').attr("data-val", v);
  
}).trigger('input');
```

```css
.unit::before {
  content: attr(data-val);
}
```

```html
<input type="range" name="" class="range" min=0 max=10001 step=1 value=0>
<span class="unit">km</span>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

## Update input range thumb value

If you want the `.range-thumb` SPAN element to follow-up with your value you could:

Position your SPAN thumb absolute into a `relative` parent.
Calculate and transform your value into thumb position `px`.
Given the thumb is always at width `100` here's an example:

```js
var $range = $('.range');

$range.each(function() {

  var $thumb = $(this).next('.range-thumb');
  var max = parseInt(this.max, 10);
  var tw = 100; // Thumb width. See CSS

  $(this).on('input input.range', function() {

    var w = $(this).width();
    var val = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    var txt = val >= max ? '∞' : val;
    var xPX = val * (w - tw) / max; // Position in PX
    // var xPC = xPX * 100 / w;     // Position in % (if ever needed)

    $thumb.css({left: xPX}).attr("data-val", txt);

  });

});

$range.trigger('input.range'); // Calc on load
$(window).on("resize", () => $range.trigger("input.range")); // and on resize
```

```css
/* QuickReset */
*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

/* CUSTOM RANGE INPUT */
.range-div {
  position: relative;
}

.range {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #1299E6, #A0D9F9);
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  outline: none;
}

.range:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #1299E6;
  border-radius: 30px;
  cursor: grab;
}

.range-thumb {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  /* half :thumb width */
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  /* same as :thumb */
  height: 30px;
  /* same as :thumb */
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  pointer-events: none;
  /* ignore mouse */
}

.range-thumb::before {
  content: attr(data-val) " ";
}
```

```html
<div class="range-div">
  <input type="range" name="" class="range" min=0 max=10001 step=1 value=0>
  <span class="range-thumb">km</span>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, how can I write this into thumb now? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: You'll have to use CSS and JS: position absolute the `span`, get the input value and calculate the new span's X position.

Comment: @BerkayGunduz added an example. Hope it helps